# How to take two option in sweetalert and take action according to that option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, sweetalert

I have one Sweetalert that takes only `Ok` and  `Cancle`. If `ok` it performs option according to that.

I need two options: `With Payment` and `Without Payment`. If the user selects `With Payment` it would ask the user to enter an amount and send it to another page.

My current `order.list.js` page is look like this

```js
function completeOrder(orderID) {
  var obj = {
    order: order,
    page: page,
    customer: $("#customers_" + from).val(),

    sdate: $("#sdate_" + from).val(),
    edate: $("#edate_" + from).val(),
    Status: Status
  };

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You want to complete this order Without Payment !!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  }).then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "process/order-process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          orderID: orderID,
          status: "Completed",
          payment: "Not Paid"
        },
        beforeSend: function() {},
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.indexOf("success") >= 0) {
            swal("Good job! Your order has been completed!", {
              icon: "success",
            });
            getResult(true, 'process/order-list.php', "POST", JSON.stringify(obj), from);
          } else {
            swal("Error!", "Something went wrong!", "error");
          }
        }
      });
    } else {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Please create a snippet, So we could be help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this below

```
swal("Place the order?", {
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You want to complete this order Without Payment !!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: {
        withPayment: "With Payment",
        withOutPayment: "With out Payment",
    }
})
.then((value) => {
    switch (value) {

        case "withPayment":
            // Proceed with payment
            break;

        case "withOutPayment":
            // Proceed without payment
            break;
    }
});
```